# Difference between MOVDQA and MOVAPS x86 instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd, mov

I'm looking Intel datasheet: **Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual**  and I can't find the difference between

- **MOVDQA**: Move Aligned Double Quadword
- **MOVAPS**: Move Aligned Packed Single-Precision

In Intel datasheet I can find for both instructions:

> This instruction can be used to load an XMM register from a 128-bit
>   memory location, to store the contents of an XMM register into a
>   128-bit memory location, or to move data between two XMM registers.

The only difference is:

> To move a double quadword to or from unaligned memory locations, use
>   the MOVDQU instruction.

and

> To move packed single-precision floating-point values to or from
>   unaligned memory locations, use the MOVUPS instruction.

But I can't find the reason why two different instructions?

**So can anybody explain the difference?**

Comment: Also MOVAPD is identical to them it seems.

Comment: Note that `movaps` has smaller machine code (3 bytes minimum): `movdqa` needs an extra prefix so it's at lest 4 bytes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In functionality, they are identical.

On **some** (but not all) micro-architectures, there are timing differences due to "domain crossing penalties".  For this reason, one should generally use `movdqa` when the data is being used with integer SSE instructions, and `movaps` when the data is being used with floating-point instructions.  For more information on this subject, consult the Intel Optimization Manual, or Agner Fog's excellent microarchitecture guide.  Note that these delays are most often associated with register-register moves instead of loads or stores.

Comment: Could you link to specific manual entries? I'm having a hard time believing this because SSE registers don't have a type associated with them (the type is encoded in the instructions) therefor I don't think there are different float & integer paths. They do, however, have different op-codes and are introduced in different instruction-sets. MOVAPS is SSE1 while MOVDQA is SSE2. They also both have the same latency & throughput according to http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf

Comment: @Jasper Bekkers: You can not believe it all you like, but it's still true.  For a general discussion of domains and the bypass delays between them, see the Intel Optimization Manual (2.2.3 discusses domains on the Nehalem micro architecture, for example).  For a concrete, specific example of the hazard, see pages 86 and 87 of Agner Fog's excellent reference http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf

Comment: The pages in Agners manual seem to have changed, best just search for "Data bypass delays", there's a section per each uArch.

Comment: What about `movaps` vs. `movapd`? They are both in the floating point domain so I don't see why there are two instructions.

Comment: @Zboson: to reserve the possibility of introducing separate float / double domains in the future.  This will almost certainly never happen, but some architect thought it might many years ago.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's very useful answer (and the link)