# 8 bit shift operation in AVX2 with shifting in zeros

Tags: c, sse, simd, avx, avx2

Is there any way to rebuild the `_mm_slli_si128` instruction in AVX2 to shift an `__mm256i` register by x bytes?

The `_mm256_slli_si256` seems just to execute two `_mm_slli_si128` on a[127:0] and a[255:128].

The left shift should work on a `__m256i` like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ..., 32] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ..., 0]
```

I saw in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516585/shifting-sse-avx-registers-32-bits-left-and-right-while-shifting-in-zeros) that it is possible to create a shift with `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` for 32bit. But I need a more generic solution to shift by x bytes. Has anybody already a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you find yourself needing to do this a lot, you might want to think of an alternate approach. AVX and beyond breaks up the vectors into "lanes" of 128-bit. Cross-lane operations are very expensive. Looking at Agner Fog's docs, it looks like cross-lane operations are more expensive than misaligned memory access.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I will checkout his docs. But I don't have to use the command extensive. But it would be good if I could use SIMD commands.

Comment: Is the shift amount a compile-time constant?

Comment: yes it is compile time

Comment: @Mysticial: It's a latency penalty, not throughput.  `VPERMD y,y,y`, `VPERMQ y,y,i`, and `VPERM2I128 y,y,y,i` are all 1uop, lat=3c, throughput=1/cycle.  (And all run on port5 only in Haswell.)  I agree, if you can structure things to work without crossing lanes all the time, that's best.  But if your algo inherently benefits, and the extra latency isn't killer, then it could be a win.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

okay I implemented a function that can shift left up to 16 byte.

```
template  <unsigned int N> __m256i _mm256_shift_left(__m256i a)
{
  __m256i mask =  _mm256_srli_si256(
          _mm256_permute2x128_si256(a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,0,3,0))
          , 16-N);
  return _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_slli_si256(a,N),mask);
}
```

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   __m256i reg =  _mm256_set_epi8(32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,
                                  14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);

   __m256i result = _mm256_shift_left<1>(reg);
   for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
     printf("%2d ",((unsigned char *)&result)[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
```

The output is
`0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15  0 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31`

**Edit:** New version with new alignr instruction. 
Thanks for the hint @Evgney Kluev

```
template  <unsigned int N> __m256i _mm256_shift_left(__m256i a)
{
  __m256i mask = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,0,3,0) );
  return _mm256_alignr_epi8(a,mask,16-N);
}
```

Comment: You could optimize this by using `_mm256_alignr_epi8` instead of both shifts and "or".

Comment: @EvgenyKluev thanks thats really a nice instruction. I could reduce it now to two instructions.

Comment: Does anyone know why VPALIGNRB (_mm256_alignr_epi8) is not in Agner Fog's instruction tables?  I want to know the latency and throughput.

Comment: @Zboson: I don't know why Agner Fog skipped it. But [this resource](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306C3_Haswell_InstLatX64.txt) reports both latency and throughput to be exactly one clock.

Comment: Old comment, so maybe it was missing 1.5 years ago, but `PALIGNR v,v,i / v,v,v,i` is listed for Haswell in Agner Fog's insn tables.  He only lists insns with the V prefix if there is no non-AVX version.  Otherwise the non-V mnemonic is there, and you have to look at the args to see if there's a different entry if there's a difference between using it on `xmm` and `ymm` args.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: heh, yup.  I neglected to include the latency and throughput though.  Oh well, pretty much all in-lane shuffles have the same latency and throughput on Haswell.