# Shifting 2 registers together as one

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, shift

I have `eax`, and `edx` and I would like to treat them like 1 register and shift them both without losing any bits.

for example, if I have `0` in edx and `0110 1111 0100 1111 0110 1111 0100 1111` in eax, and I would do `shl eax , 23` it would give me `0000 0000 0011 0111 1010 0111 1011 0111` in edx, and leave eax with `1010 0111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`
is there a command to do that in x86 assembly? or would I have to make my own procedure to do that?

Comment: Did you mean `1010 0111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` in eax, i.e. it is shifted too, or do you not care about `eax` ending value? BTW, you will probably want to use http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SHLD.html

Comment: yea , I did mean, thank you

Comment: May be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39276634/4271923  ... (but I was looking for duplicate explaining the `shld` itself, and didn't find it, I'm considering producing an short answer with simple example, if nobody will find some duplicate or answer it sooner)

Comment: [Shifting big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10526840/995714)

Comment: Already use what Ped7g suggested, Thanks anyways! @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc