# optimize 32-bit value construction

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation

So, I have the following code:

```
uint32_t val;
if (swap) {
   val = ((uint32_t)a & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint32_t)b << 16);
} else {
   val = ((uint32_t)b & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint32_t)a << 16);
}
```

Is there a way to optimize it, and have `swap` checking *somehow* embedded in the statement?

Comment: What determines `swap`?

Comment: Why do you think the present version is suboptimal?

Comment: What about the [? operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c)? Keep in mind this does not optimize runtime at all.

Comment: `swap` is likely a compile time constant or something established once in the course of a particular set of work. E.g., one might be interpreting data received from a little-endian or a big-endian system. Rarely does one interpret data from a single stream that contains both little-endian and big-endian data. So a strategy for optimizing this code would be to create two sets of code without the `swap` test in them, one set of code for each case. Select one either at compile time or when beginning a course of work, as appropriate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil no. Imagine RS485 network with different sensors. Some are big endian some little. You need to correct store the data depending on the sensor read

Comment: @P__J__: “Rarely.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil often if you are embedded  engineer. Even now I  write software for such a master device.

Comment: @P__J__: In this case, P(E) < P(E|C).

Comment: @EricPostpischil P(C)  usually do not touch this low level problems

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is to avoid a branch, then you can write this:

```
val = ((!!swap) * (uint32_t)a + (!swap) * (uint32_t)b) & 0x0000ffff)
        | (((!!swap) * (uint32_t)b + (!swap) * (uint32_t)a) << 16);
```

This uses the fact that `!x` evaluates to 0 whenever `swap` is truthy and to 1 whenever `swap` is falsey, and so also `!!x` evaluates to 1 when `x` is truthy, even though `x` may not itself be 1.  Multiplying by the result selects either `a` or `b` as appropriate.

Note, however, that instead of one compare and branch you now have multiple logical and arithmetic operations.  It is not at all clear that that would provide a performance improvement in practice.

---

Courtesy of @ChristianGibbons:

[Provided that `a` and `b` are guaranteed non-negative and less than 2<sup>16</sup>,] you can simplify this approach substantially by removing the bitwise AND component and applying the multiplication to the shifts instead of to the arguments:

```
val = ((uint32_t) a << (16 * !swap)) | ((uint32_t)b << (16 * !!swap));
```

That stands a better chance of outperforming the original code (but is still by no means certain to do so), but in that case a more fair comparison would be with a version of the original that relies on the same properties of the inputs:

```
uint32_t val;
if (swap) {
   val = (uint32_t)a | ((uint32_t)b << 16);
} else {
   val = (uint32_t)b | ((uint32_t)a << 16);
}
```

Comment: it works rather nicely on Clang and GCC totally misses it... got 4 imuls too :F

Comment: Oops, I removed my comment because I had improved upon it further and turned it into an answer.

Comment: No worries, @ChristianGibbons, and thanks for the comment to establish that I've cribbed from a comment, not your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There us not too much to optimize

Here you have two versions

```
typedef union
{
    uint16_t u16[2];
    uint32_t u32;
}D32_t;


uint32_t foo(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, int swap)
{
    D32_t da = {.u32 = a}, db = {.u32 = b}, val;

    if(swap)
    {
        val.u16[0] = da.u16[1];
        val.u16[1] = db.u16[0];
    }
    else
    {
        val.u16[0] = db.u16[1];
        val.u16[1] = da.u16[0];
    }

    return val.u32;
}


uint32_t foo2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, int swap)
{
    uint32_t val;
    if (swap) 
    {
        val = ((uint32_t)a & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint32_t)b << 16);
    } 
    else 
    {
        val = ((uint32_t)b & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint32_t)a << 16);
    }

    return val;
}
```

the generated code is almost the same.

clang:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        mov     eax, edi
        test    edx, edx
        mov     ecx, esi
        cmove   ecx, edi
        cmove   eax, esi
        shrd    eax, ecx, 16
        ret
foo2:                                   # @foo2
        movzx   ecx, si
        movzx   eax, di
        shl     edi, 16
        or      edi, ecx
        shl     esi, 16
        or      eax, esi
        test    edx, edx
        cmove   eax, edi
        ret
```

gcc:

```
foo:
        test    edx, edx
        je      .L2
        shr     edi, 16
        mov     eax, esi
        mov     edx, edi
        sal     eax, 16
        mov     ax, dx
        ret
.L2:
        shr     esi, 16
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     edx, esi
        sal     eax, 16
        mov     ax, dx
        ret
foo2:
        test    edx, edx
        je      .L6
        movzx   eax, di
        sal     esi, 16
        or      eax, esi
        ret
.L6:
        movzx   eax, si
        sal     edi, 16
        or      eax, edi
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/F4zOnf

As you see clang likes unions, gcc shifts.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am surprised that gcc is genereting so bad code when unions are used.

Comment: I didn't even know about the existence of SHRD until now.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to John Bollinger's answer that avoids any branching, I came up with the following to try to reduce the amount of operations performed, especially multiplication.

```
uint8_t shift_mask = (uint8_t) !swap * 16;
val = ((uint32_t) a << (shift_mask)) | ((uint32_t)b << ( 16 ^ shift_mask  ));
```

Neither compiler actually even uses a multiplication instruction since the only multiplication here is by a power of two, so it just uses a simple left shift to construct the value that will be used to shift either `a` or `b`.

Dissassembly of original with Clang -O2

```
0000000000000000 <cat>:
   0:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
   2:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
   4:   66 0f 45 c7             cmovne %di,%ax
   8:   66 0f 45 fe             cmovne %si,%di
   c:   0f b7 c0                movzwl %ax,%eax
   f:   c1 e7 10                shl    $0x10,%edi
  12:   09 f8                   or     %edi,%eax
  14:   c3                      retq   
  15:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  1c:   00 00 00 00
```

Dissassembly of new version with Clang -O2

```
0000000000000000 <cat>:
   0:   80 f2 01                xor    $0x1,%dl
   3:   0f b6 ca                movzbl %dl,%ecx
   6:   c1 e1 04                shl    $0x4,%ecx
   9:   d3 e7                   shl    %cl,%edi
   b:   83 f1 10                xor    $0x10,%ecx
   e:   d3 e6                   shl    %cl,%esi
  10:   09 fe                   or     %edi,%esi
  12:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  14:   c3                      retq   
  15:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  1c:   00 00 00 00
```

Disassembly of original version with gcc -O2

```
0000000000000000 <cat>:
   0:   84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
   2:   75 0c                   jne    10 <cat+0x10>
   4:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
   6:   0f b7 f6                movzwl %si,%esi
   9:   c1 e0 10                shl    $0x10,%eax
   c:   09 f0                   or     %esi,%eax
   e:   c3                      retq   
   f:   90                      nop
  10:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  12:   0f b7 ff                movzwl %di,%edi
  15:   c1 e0 10                shl    $0x10,%eax
  18:   09 f8                   or     %edi,%eax
  1a:   c3                      retq
```

Disassembly of new version with gcc -O2

```
0000000000000000 <cat>:
   0:   83 f2 01                xor    $0x1,%edx
   3:   0f b7 c6                movzwl %si,%eax
   6:   0f b7 ff                movzwl %di,%edi
   9:   c1 e2 04                shl    $0x4,%edx
   c:   89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
   e:   83 f1 10                xor    $0x10,%ecx
  11:   d3 e0                   shl    %cl,%eax
  13:   89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
  15:   d3 e7                   shl    %cl,%edi
  17:   09 f8                   or     %edi,%eax
  19:   c3                      retq
```

***EDIT:***
As John Bollinger pointed out, this solution was written under the assumption that `a` and `b` were unsigned values rendering the bit-masking redundant.  If this approach is to be used with signed values under 32-bits, then it would need modification:

```
uint8_t shift_mask = (uint8_t) !swap * 16;
val = ((uint32_t) (a & 0xFFFF) << (shift_mask)) | ((uint32_t) (b & 0xFFFF) << ( 16 ^ shift_mask  ));
```

I won't go too far into the disassembly of this version, but here's the clang output at -O2:

```
0000000000000000 <cat>:
   0:   80 f2 01                xor    $0x1,%dl
   3:   0f b6 ca                movzbl %dl,%ecx
   6:   c1 e1 04                shl    $0x4,%ecx
   9:   0f b7 d7                movzwl %di,%edx
   c:   d3 e2                   shl    %cl,%edx
   e:   0f b7 c6                movzwl %si,%eax
  11:   83 f1 10                xor    $0x10,%ecx
  14:   d3 e0                   shl    %cl,%eax
  16:   09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
  18:   c3                      retq   
  19:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

In response to P__J__ in regards to performance versus his union solution, here is what clang spits out at `-O3` for the version of this code that is safe for dealing with signed types:

```
0000000000000000 <cat>:
   0:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
   2:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
   4:   66 0f 45 c7             cmovne %di,%ax
   8:   66 0f 45 fe             cmovne %si,%di
   c:   0f b7 c0                movzwl %ax,%eax
   f:   c1 e7 10                shl    $0x10,%edi
  12:   09 f8                   or     %edi,%eax
  14:   c3                      retq   
  15:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  1c:   00 00 00 00
```

It is a bit closer to the union solution in total instructions, but does not use SHRD which, according to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277714/8513665) answer, it takes 4 clocks to perform on an intel skylake processor and uses up several operation units.  I'd be mildly curious how they would each actually perform.

Comment: As I mention in my own answer, this approach supposes that the `a` and `b` inputs are both guaranteed to be non-negative and less than 2^16.  That seems plausible given the apparent nature of the task being performed, in which case the bitwise AND in the original post is unnecessary.  But if that's *not* guaranteed, then this will not work correctly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point on the signedness assumption.  I wrote my test code into a function that with an argument list of `(uint16_t a, uint16_t b, _Bool swap)`; I definitely made an assumption this was intended to be used with unsigned 16-bit values.  I'll make an edit to clarify the assumption.

Comment: @P__J__ Does that take into account the number of clocks each operation might take?  I did a quick search on the SHRD operation, and the first result was a question on SO about how slow SHRD is.  Also, I noticed you were using `-O3`.  I found the disassembly of mine to be completely different when I bumped up to `O3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = swap ? ((uint32_t)a & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint32_t)b << 16) : ((uint32_t)b & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint32_t)a << 16);
```

This will achieve the "embedding" you ask for. However, I don't recommend this as it makes readability worse and no runtime optimization.

Comment: `?` does not change anything regarding the generated code efficiency

Comment: As I said in my answer. I believe my post answers OP's question as s/he phrased it. It of course doesn't change runtime or any efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with `-O3`. [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/4PWkqX) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/BTjOds) have slightly different strategies for 64-bit processors. GCC generates code with branch whereas Clang will run both branches and then use conditional move. Both GCC and Clang will generate a *"zero-extend short to int"* instruction instead of `and`.

Using `?:` didn't change the generated code in either.

The Clang version does seem more efficient.

All in all, both would generate the same code *if* you didn't need the swap.