How to use SIMD effectively to count 4-character matches in a large word-search grid (including vertical and diagonal)?
For day 4 of the 2024 advent of code there's a problem where you need to find how many "XMAS" strings are contained in a grid of characters such as
MMMSXXMASM
MSAMXMSMSA
AMXSXMAAMM
MSAMASMSMX
XMASAMXAMM
XXAMMXXAMA
SMSMSASXSS
SAXAMASAAA
MAMMMXMMMM
MXMXAXMASX

The word can appear in any of the 8 directions: horizontally (up/down) / vertically (left/right), or any of the 4 diagonals.
It's unclear from the problem statement if the grid size is intended to be fixed.
The actual test-case they give you is 140x140.

The way I solved that problem was to load all 32 characters of the 8 possible directions starting from an X into a SIMD register and comparing it to a mask.
That worked and is relatively fast (it reached 460 MB/s when I increased the input file size to test its limit) but when talking about our solutions on a discord server containing a lot of developers, and a few ones with over 15 years of professional experience, one of them told me that for this specific problem the use of SIMD instructions isn't what would make the code run faster and the underlying algorithm itself is more important.
So I'm wondering, in what situations is SIMD worth it? How do I recognize a situation where using SIMD instructions would make a noticeable difference? I thought that comparing all 32 characters in 1 instruction would make a big difference instead of nesting 2 for loops but I might have been wrong?
typedef struct {
    std::vector<char> chars;
    uint32_t line_length;
} Data;

Data readFile() {
    std::ifstream file("./input/day4_input.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<char> buffer(size); 
    file.read(buffer.data(), size);
    file.close();

    uint32_t line_length = std::ranges::find(buffer, '\n') - buffer.begin();
    buffer.erase(std::remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '\n'), buffer.end());

    Data input_data { buffer, line_length };
    return input_data;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Data idata = readFile();

    auto coordsToIdx = [&idata] (uint32_t i, uint32_t j) -> uint32_t { return i*idata.line_length + j; };
    auto idxToCoords = [&idata] (uint32_t idx) -> std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> {
        return std::make_pair(static_cast<uint32_t>(idx / idata.line_length), static_cast<uint32_t>(idx % idata.line_length));
    };

    unsigned int res = 0;

    const __m256i _mask = _mm256_setr_epi8(
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S',
        'X', 'M', 'A', 'S'
    );

    std::array<int, 8> out_buff;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < idata.chars.size(); i++) {
        if(idata.chars[i] != 'X') continue; 

        char buff[32] = {0};

        std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> coords = idxToCoords(i);
        bool u = coords.first >= 3;
        bool d = coords.first <= (idata.chars.size() / idata.line_length) - 4; // 0 indexed
        bool l = coords.second >= 3;
        bool r = coords.second <= idata.line_length - 4;

        if(u) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first - c, coords.second)];
        if(u && r) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 4] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first - c, coords.second + c)];
        if(r) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 8] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first, coords.second + c)];
        if(d && r) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 12] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first + c, coords.second + c)];
        if(d) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 16] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first + c, coords.second)];
        if(d && l) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 20] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first + c, coords.second - c)];
        if(l) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 24] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first, coords.second - c)];
        if(u && l) for(size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++) buff[c + 28] = idata.chars[coordsToIdx(coords.first - c, coords.second - c)];

        __m256i _block = _mm256_loadu_epi8(buff);
        __m256i _cmpeq = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(_block, _mask);
        _mm256_storeu_epi32(out_buff.data(), _cmpeq);
        
        // Contains signed 32 bits integers for each direction
        // If a direction match, all bits are set to 1
        // Which is -1. So we substract the total to add it instead
        res -= std::accumulate(out_buff.begin(), out_buff.end(), 0);  
    }

    std::cout << "Result is : << res << std::endl;
}


The JUCE docs give some nice practical examples of SIMD instructions can be used effectively. In particular, look at the section on conditional statements. Rather than if or else then a calculation,  you can construct your code in such a way that you do more than one calculation, but only choose the result you need. Linear algebra is also a prime candidate, especially when compiler optimisations fail to auto-vectorise loops.

I believe a good SIMD algorithm would be significantly faster. Nowadays SIMD can even be used for complex things like json parsing or encoding conversion/validation

Hard to say in general, but such phrases as "the underlying algorithm itself is more important" are commonly used by programmers who don't use SIMD or they believe the propaganda that algorithmic complexity is all that matters. Most programmers don't have experience with SIMD after all, and that includes most long-time programmers.

Well, did the other devs offer any solutions of their own? As Linus Torvalds famously said: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." 460 MiB/s sounds pretty good

A link to the specific code challenge and a posting of your own code would also help the discussion

@Homer512 memories are around 20 GiB/s . 460 MiB/s is low, those are rookie numbers, if you aren't hitting the memory bandwidth limit then there is room for improvement.

@AhmedAEK Arg, you are right. My brain was still in disk I/O land. 460 MiB/s is what, 1 byte per 8 clock cycles? Something's wrong there. Anyway. The generic strstr has an SSE2 version while the AVX512 version was removed, though it's still present on my system

@Homer512 The specific person who said that SIMD wouldn't be the thing to drastically speed up the algorithm hasn't shared any code no. The only people who have have sent algorithms that were up to 3x slower than mine. I edited the original post to include my code. The input file is rather small so I figured I'd buffer it all in memory first

SIMD isn't trivial to use for this, unlike for pure-vertical c[i] = a[i] + b[i].  And vectorization strategy will depend on ISA, e.g. turning compare results into sums of counts.  Also, density of matches and of false-positive prefixes are factors in which strategy is best.  In this case, with a 4-byte needle, we probably just brute-force check at all 4 offsets, with overlap at ends of vectors so each possible appearance is checked exactly once.

Is the grid size fixed?  Is it flat text with newlines, or can it be a 2D array without newlines?  Ar matches that span lines supposed to count?  Oh, no I see you mention direction, like a word-search.  Maybe like a chess bitboard, we'd want to AND byte- compare results to check for an X at the start, an M in the second, etc, for the vertical and diagonal directions.

The grid size is crucial. If it's really just 10 bytes horizontally, that makes vectorization much harder. If the size is significantly larger, you can use an overlapped brute-force check per direction. Something like this (godbolt) which checks 32 start positions in 4 memory loads in one direction

Just out of fun when i tried to do a multithreaded version, a version with memcmp and no simd was almost 2.5 times faster, because simd registers are limited and cannot make use of hyperthreading while memcmp can, simd was 250 MB/sec while memcmp was 580 MB/sec. might post about it later, i think 1 GB/sec is possible if you replace memcmp with std::apply

@PeterCordes The grid size for the exercice is static yes. The example data given is 10x10 but the actual data was 140x140? When testing my algorithm's limits I increased it to 2.5 mil x 140. When reading the file I flattened the array for cache locality but maybe that's not the best thing to do in this case

@AhmedAEK I admit I have some trouble understanding your loop. With my current understanding, _mm256_loadu_si256 loads 256 bits of contiguous data starting from the given address, wouldn't there be overlaps calling it with haystack+i then haystack+i+1 and so on?

@AhmedAEK: x86-64 glibc memcmp uses YMM vector registers if available.  If for example, vector shuffle ALU throughput is the main bottleneck in your whole thing, then you're right that hyperthreading wouldn't help.  But if L1d cache load bandwidth is a bottlenck for memcmp, hyperthreading also won't help much unless you have a lot of work outside of memcmp.  Also, memcmp itself sucks: it doesn't give you the match position.  Or were you using 4-byte memcmp to get unaligned scalar cmp dword [mem], 'xmas' (NASM syntax)?

@PeterCordes yep, 4 byte memcmp, no simd emitted whatsoever, godbolt link, you can increase repeats to run it for longer outside of godbolt.

@user555045 Considering Advent of Code is a casual algorithmic-competition-like event, that shouldn't be the case. There should be no SIMD knowledge required and relatively little algorithmic knowledge required, it's mostly just ability to quickly put together a code without bugs or overcomplications.

"So I'm wondering, in what situations is SIMD worth it? How do I recognize a situation where using SIMD instructions would make a noticeable difference?" Get a feel for it from experience. There isn't any strict rule (apart from obvious cyclic definition "when the SIMDed operations would be a large % of all operations"), but it tends to happen e.g. when you're processing big data buffers in simple loops. In this case, it seems your bottleneck is loading characters, not comparing them.

@Xellos: IDK what you were replying to user555 about.  You said "that shouldn't be the case", but like we all now agree, nobody said anything to disagree with in the first place.  The only way in which "that shouldn't be the case" makes sense to me is wishing that people wouldn't make incorrect statements about SIMD not being useful.  I've been playing around with the bitboard idea, and although a 140x140 board is rather inconvenient (just slightly too large for 128-bit vectors so I need AVX2 lane-crossing stuff) I suspect there's a large speedup making a bitmap of X,M,A, and S and bitwise AND

Xellos: Anyway, you and @user555045 (and I) should probably just delete the earlier comments relating to your first one, since it's just clutter.

Anyway, it's slow going figuring out how to efficiently unroll a loop that reuses vector shift results, since bit-shifting an __m256i by a couple bits takes a shuffle and multiple vertical shift/OR ops.  At least I can basically just rotate since there are enough high zeros to shift in from.  But with only 16 YMM regs (until AVX-512), I'm probably going to have to spill some of them, or even make an array indexed by row & 7 or something for a circular buffer of recently-generated shifted vectors to be reused when checking horizontal and diagonal.

Work-in-progress: https://godbolt.org/z/9j56jnjGa doesn't reuse vector bit-shift results, and doesn't count diagonals.  https://uica.uops.info/ predicts Skylake can run 1 iteration of its inner loop in 18.5 cycles, Rocket Lake 17.33 (handling horizontals on one row of 140 chars, and verticals where one end is that row, but not diagonals yet.  And without unrolling and shift-result reuse which hopefully more than make up for it)  It would be equal speed per row with a wider grid up to 253 chars, other than the preprocessing to build the bitmaps with vpcmpeqb / vpmovmskb.

General topic
I think that person you were talking to has fallen into a bit of a false dichotomy. Using advanced algorithms and vectorization are not mutually exclusive (though it may be harder). Case in point: The task is a variation on the needle-haystack problem for which strstr is a standard implementation. Glibc implements an advanced algorithm for this (modified Horspool) but also has an SSE2-accelerated version of it. In contrast, they removed their AVX512-accelerated version, seemingly because it implemented the naive algorithm instead.
Tasks that are truly unsuitable for vectorization are such with

complex branching logic
dominated by loop-carried dependencies which are not associative
scattered input and output (until we get good scatter/gather support)

What that person is right about is that at first you should focus on the algorithm before starting with vectorization or parallelization. The latter two can only give you linear performance gains. Choosing a better algorithm can get much more; but modifying vectorized or parallelized code is much harder.
However, here we have a very specific task: The needle that we search in our haystack is exactly 4 bytes and it appears very frequently in the input data. Complex algorithms and big-O notation are meaningless for small numbers. This is the domain of simple brute-force algorithms.
Vectorized algorithm
Here is my take. To understand it, we build it ground up. Let's focus on the horizontal match, forward direction only, just a single row. What we want is a vectorized form of
int count = 0;
for(int col = 0; col <= cols - 4; ++col)
  count += (haystack[col] == 'X') & (haystack[col+1] == 'M')
           & (haystack[col+2] == 'A') & (haystack[col+3] == 'S');

With AVX512, we can compare 64 entries at once like this:
const __m512i xvec = _mm512_set1_epi8('X');
const __m512i mvec = _mm512_set1_epi8('M');
const __m512i avec = _mm512_set1_epi8('A');
const __m512i svec = _mm512_set1_epi8('S');
for(int col = 0; col <= cols - 64 - 4; col += 64) {
  const char* colptr = haystack + col;
  const __m512i c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr);
  const __m512i c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 1);
  const __m512i c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2);
  const __m512i c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3);
  __mmask64 fe = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, xvec);
  fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c2, mvec);
  fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c3, avec);
  fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c4, svec);
  count += _popcnt64(fe);
}

We do an overlapped load for each value, compare them and count the bits set in the mask. You will find this overlapped load pattern in many applications such as convolution.
Handling the tail end is simple enough in AVX512: You just load with a mask. Since a zero-byte cannot match our needle, the rest of the algorithm can stay the same.
int col;
for(col = 0; col <= cols - 64 - 4; ++col) {
  ... // (main loop)
}
const std::uint64_t tailcount = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(
      std::min(64, cols - col));
if(tailcount) {
  const std::uint64_t tailmask = (~std::uint64_t{0}) >> (64 - tailcount);
  const char* colptr = haystack + col;
  const __m512i c1 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr);
  const __m512i c2 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 1, colptr + 1);
  const __m512i c3 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 2, colptr + 2);
  const __m512i c4 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 3, colptr + 3);
  ... // same as main loop from here
}

Now we have to extend it to a 2D grid and the other 7 directions.
Checking the reverse direction can simply be done with a second set of comparisons, only reversing the xvec to svec order.
The vertical and diagonal checks are simple since instead of advancing one column, we advance one row plus minus 1 column. Doing the range checks is error prone, otherwise it's the same.
Here is the full algorithm. I've verified the result but I cannot rule out edge cases that aren't covered by the test data.
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <immintrin.h>


struct Grid
{
  std::string buf;
  int rows, cols;
};


static Grid read_grid(const char* filepath)
{
  Grid grid {};
  std::ifstream infile { filepath };
  std::string tmp;
  while(std::getline(infile, tmp)) {
    grid.rows += 1;
    grid.cols = tmp.size();
    grid.buf += tmp;
  }
  return grid;
}

static int count_xmas_dense(const Grid& grid)
{
  const char* gridptr = grid.buf.c_str();
  const std::ptrdiff_t rows = grid.rows;
  const std::ptrdiff_t cols = grid.cols;
  const __m512i xvec = _mm512_set1_epi8('X');
  const __m512i mvec = _mm512_set1_epi8('M');
  const __m512i avec = _mm512_set1_epi8('A');
  const __m512i svec = _mm512_set1_epi8('S');
  auto check_forward_backward =
    [&](__m512i c1, __m512i c2, __m512i c3, __m512i c4) {
      // check forward
      __mmask64 fe = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, xvec);
      fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c2, mvec);
      fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c3, avec);
      fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c4, svec);
      int rtrn = _popcnt64(fe);
      // check backward
      __mmask64 be = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, svec);
      be = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be, c2, avec);
      be = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be, c3, mvec);
      be = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be, c4, xvec);
      rtrn += _popcnt64(be);
      return rtrn;
  };
  int rtrn = 0;
  if(cols > 3) {
    // check left to right and right to left
    for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
      const char* rowptr = gridptr + row * cols;
      std::ptrdiff_t col;
      for(col = 0; col <= cols - 64 - 3; col += 64) {
        const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
        const __m512i c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr);
        const __m512i c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 1);
        const __m512i c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2);
        const __m512i c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3);
        rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
      }
      const std::uint64_t tailcount = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(
            std::min<std::ptrdiff_t>(64, cols - col));
      if(!tailcount)
        continue;
      const std::uint64_t tailmask = (~std::uint64_t{0}) >> (64 - tailcount);
      const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
      const __m512i c1 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr);
      const __m512i c2 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 1, colptr + 1);
      const __m512i c3 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 2, colptr + 2);
      const __m512i c4 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 3, colptr + 3);
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
    }
  }
  if(rows > 3) {
    // check top to bottom and bottom up
    for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row <= rows - 4; ++row) {
      const char* rowptr = gridptr + row * cols;
      std::ptrdiff_t col;
      for(col = 0; col <= cols - 64; col += 64) {
        const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
        const __m512i c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr);
        const __m512i c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + cols);
        const __m512i c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2 * cols);
        const __m512i c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3 * cols);
        rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
      }
      const std::uint64_t tailcount = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(
            std::min<std::ptrdiff_t>(64, cols - col));
      if(! tailcount)
        continue;
      const std::uint64_t tailmask = (~std::uint64_t{0}) >> (64 - tailcount);
      const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
      const __m512i c1 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr);
      const __m512i c2 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr + cols);
      const __m512i c3 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr + 2 * cols);
      const __m512i c4 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr + 3 * cols);
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
    }
  }
  if(rows > 3 && cols > 3) {
    for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row <= rows - 4; ++row) {
      const char* rowptr = gridptr + row * cols;
      std::ptrdiff_t col;
      for(col = 0; col <= cols - 64 - 3; col += 64) {
        const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
        // top left to bottom right
        __m512i c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr);
        __m512i c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + cols + 1);
        __m512i c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2 * (cols + 1));
        __m512i c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3 * (cols + 1));
        rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
        // top right to bottom left
        c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3);
        c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2 + cols);
        c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 1 + 2 * cols);
        c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3 * cols);
        rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
      }
      const std::uint64_t tailcount = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(
            std::min<std::ptrdiff_t>(64, cols - col));
      const std::uint64_t tailmask = (~std::uint64_t{0}) >> (64 - tailcount);
      const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
      __m512i c1 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr);
      __m512i c2 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 1, colptr + cols + 1);
      __m512i c3 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 2, colptr + 2 * (cols + 1));
      __m512i c4 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 3, colptr + 3 * (cols + 1));
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
      c1 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 3, colptr + 3);
      c2 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 2, colptr + 2 + cols);
      c3 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask >> 1, colptr + 1 + 2 * cols);
      c4 = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8(tailmask, colptr + 3 * cols);
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
    }
  }
  return rtrn;
}
int main()
{
  Grid grid = read_grid("xmas.txt");
  std::cout << grid.rows << ' ' << grid.cols << ' ' << grid.buf.size() <<'\n';
  using clock_t = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  auto t1 = clock_t::now();
  int result = count_xmas_dense(grid);
  auto t2 = clock_t::now();
  auto nanos = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1);
  double throughput = (grid.buf.size() / (1024. * 1024.)) / (nanos.count() * 1e-9);
  std::cout << result
        << ' ' << throughput <<  " MiB/s\n";
}

If I extend the test data file by a factor of 10,000 (1400140 rows by 140 columns), I achieve a throughput of 3.9 GiB/s.
AVX2 version
Converting this to AVX2 should not be too hard. For the comparison you simply use _mm256_cmpeq_epi8, followed by _mm256_and_si256 to merge the results and _mm256_movemask_epi8 to get the bit mask.
For the tail, you need to unroll one iteration with 16 bytes and then probably a scalar loop for the last few.
Variations
You can try to increase the instruction-level parallelism in the comparison by avoiding the input dependency from one comparison to the next through the mask input. However, on my platform (Tigerlake) this is slightly slower. I guess the extra front-end pressure isn't worth it.
      __mmask64 fe1 = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, xvec);
      __mmask64 fe2 = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c2, mvec);
      fe1 = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe1, c3, avec);
      fe2 = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe2, c4, svec);
      int rtrn = _popcnt64(fe1 & fe2);
      __mmask64 be1 = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, svec);
      __mmask64 be2 = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c2, avec);
      be1 = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be1, c3, mvec);
      be2 = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be2, c4, xvec);
      rtrn += _popcnt64(be1 & be2);

In the top-down loop, you can avoid redundant loads by rotating the vectors that we already have. The same could be done with the diagonal patterns. However, this is only half as fast as the trivial version in my tests. I assume the extra stress on the cache and TLB due to the transposed access pattern outdoes any gains.
    std::ptrdiff_t col;
    __m512i c1, c2, c3, c4;
    for(col = 0; col <= cols - 64; col += 64) {
      const char* colptr = gridptr + col;
      c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr);
      c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + cols);
      c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2 * cols);
      for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 3; row < rows; ++row) {
        c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + row * cols);
        rtrn += check_forward_backward(c1, c2, c3, c4);
        c1 = c2;
        c2 = c3;
        c3 = c4;
      }
    }

Further possible improvements:

Blocking. I doubt that we are constrained by memory bandwidth but blockwise execution of the three loops could still improve the cache hit rate. This might also redeem the alternative top-down loop above. Alternatively we can fold all three loops into one with some extra logic for the grid borders where not all patterns are possible. But this gets tedious fast
Since the number of rows is pretty small, the overhead for setting up the tail masks is relevant. This can be moved out of the loops
If the needle was much less frequent, we could use some short-circuit logic, e.g. not loading c2 and c3 if not either c1 or c4 contain at least one X
Since we control the input parsing, we can pad each row to a multiple of 64 (including a minimum padding of 3 for the diagonals) to avoid the whole tail masking. If we pair this with an aligned allocator such as posix_memalign, then at least the c1 vector will be properly aligned, which generally has a positive impact on AVX512
The loops are highly redundant. One can probably make a much smaller code with an inline helper function that takes the stride as an argument
Parallelization should be trivial with something like

int rtrn = 0;
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:rtrn)
{
# pragma omp for nowait
  for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    // left to right and reverse
  }
# pragma omp for nowait
  for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row <= rows - 4; ++row) {
    // top to bottom
  }
# pragma omp for nowait
  for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row <= rows - 4; ++row) {
    // diagonal
  }
}
return rtrn;

Update
Here is a version incorporating those changes. Adding some padding to get rid of the tail masks brought performance up from 3.9 to 4.8 GiB/s. Folding the loops into one for better caching improved it to 5.7 GiB/s. Parallelization got it up to 9.8 GiB/s. Interestingly, alignment of the rows reduced performance to 50%. Maybe some issue with aliasing?
struct Grid
{
  std::string buf;
  int rows, cols, stride;
};

static Grid read_grid(const char* filepath)
{
  Grid grid {};
  std::ifstream infile { filepath };
  std::string tmp;
  if(! std::getline(infile, grid.buf))
    return grid;
  const std::size_t cols = grid.buf.size();
  // adding padding to remove tail: 3.9 GiB to 4.8 GiB
  const std::size_t stride = cols + 64 + 3;
  const std::size_t padding = stride - cols;
  grid.buf.append(padding, '\0');
  grid.cols = static_cast<int>(cols);
  grid.stride = static_cast<int>(stride);
  grid.rows = 1;
  while(std::getline(infile, tmp)) {
    if(tmp.size() != cols)
      throw std::runtime_error("input format error");
    grid.rows += 1;
    grid.buf += tmp;
    grid.buf.append(padding, '\0');
  }
  return grid;
}

static int count_xmas_dense(const Grid& grid)
{
  const char* gridptr = grid.buf.c_str();
  const std::ptrdiff_t rows = grid.rows;
  const std::ptrdiff_t cols = grid.cols;
  const std::ptrdiff_t stride = grid.stride;
  const __m512i xvec = _mm512_set1_epi8('X');
  const __m512i mvec = _mm512_set1_epi8('M');
  const __m512i avec = _mm512_set1_epi8('A');
  const __m512i svec = _mm512_set1_epi8('S');
  auto check_forward_backward =
    [&](const char* colptr, std::ptrdiff_t stride) {
      const __m512i c1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr);
      const __m512i c2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + stride);
      const __m512i c3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 2 * stride);
      const __m512i c4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(colptr + 3 * stride);
      // check forward
      __mmask64 fe = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, xvec);
      fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c2, mvec);
      fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c3, avec);
      fe = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(fe, c4, svec);
      int rtrn = _popcnt64(fe);
      // check backward
      __mmask64 be = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(c1, svec);
      be = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be, c2, avec);
      be = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be, c3, mvec);
      be = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi8_mask(be, c4, xvec);
      rtrn += _popcnt64(be);
      return rtrn;
  };
  int rtrn = 0;
# pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:rtrn)
  for(std::ptrdiff_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    const char* rowptr = gridptr + row * stride;
    std::ptrdiff_t col;
    for(col = 0; col <= cols - 4; col += 64) {
      const char* colptr = rowptr + col;
      // check left to right and right to left
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(colptr, 1);
      if(row > rows - 4)
        continue;
      // check top to bottom and bottom up
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(colptr, stride);
      // top left to bottom right
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(colptr, stride + 1);
      // top right to bottom left
      rtrn += check_forward_backward(colptr + 3, stride - 1);
    }
    // last top-down
    rtrn += check_forward_backward(rowptr + col, stride);
  }
  return rtrn;
}


I've been working on a version that makes X, M, A, and S bitmaps from the input data, allowing us to load a whole row of bits into a __m256i.  Shifting by 1, 2, or 3 bits sucks for __m256i especially with AVX512VBMI2 for vpshldq element-wise double-precision shift.  But hopefully pays for itself.  https://godbolt.org/z/9j56jnjGa doesn't have diagonals done yet, but also doesn't have reuse of shift results or an unrolled loop.  uiCA says it should be about 18.5 cycles per iteration on Skylake (per 1 row, checking horizontal in it and verticals up and down to/from it.)

But yeah just brute-forcing characters directly is pretty solid and scales easily to any row width.  And easier to write for sure; mine's nowhere near done in terms of all the optimizations I've thought of.  It should benefit very nicely from AVX512 VPOPCNTDQ, and from AVX512's 32 vector regs.  And maybe from doing 2 rows at once in lanes of a __m512i, especially on Zen 5.

8 cycles per row with -march=icelake-client using 256-bit vectors, if I use vpopcntq instead of b to make vpsadbw unnecessary.  (Not counting building the map, another several cycles per row.)  GCC finds many uses for vpternlogd to do 2 ANDs in one instruction, left-shifting a __m256i by a couple bits is only 2 insns instead of 4, and vector popcount is much cheaper and doesn't need any vectors constants tying up registers.  ICL/Zen4 feature level of AVX-512 is a huge win even with only 256-bit vectors.

@PeterCordes I'd love to see that as a full answer. That type of bit mask handling sounds like it could be a generally useful tool

I posted an answer.  I was underestimating how much more work diagonals were.  But on the plus side, it looks like clang 18 -march=znver4 -O3 unrolled for me and kept the recently-shifted vectors in registers, so I don't have to manually write that to see how it performs.  Also, I got to try this out on the new Zen 5 system I'm building for my dad, taking full advantage of its wide pipeline, bigger L1d cache, and 4 SIMD ALUs with excellent 256 and 512-bit throughput including 64-byte loads.

What clock speed is your Tiger Lake?  You mention some GiB/s numbers, but unless I missed it, don't specify enough detail about your CPU to calculate bytes / clock for comparison across microarchitectures and clock frequencies.

My Zen 5 only gets up to 3.7GHz running this with the 188MiB input file, exiting in 89 ms.  It reports 27232694 13700.9 MiB/s  or sometimes 13858.5 MiB/s.  Even with perf stat -r 40 to repeat for times, it seems happy at 3.7 GHz, not its max boost of 5.45 GHz. (Maybe it's partly OS-managed? Intel hardware P-state and turbo would turbo boost from steady load even across multiple short processes.  I don't think it's downclocking due to a mem bottleneck; it clocks high when running Prime95.) Anyway, 2.76 IPC, 3.3% L1d cache miss rate.

@PeterCordes Impressive answer. I have to study it in further detail. My CPU is an i7-11800H. The same perf stat -r 40 gives 4.0 GHz + 0.4 ins/cycle parallelized and 4.5 GHz + 1.15 ins/cycle single threaded

Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! My apologies for getting back so late work has been crazy in this end of the year. It's interesting that overlapped loads are so common in SIMD code, I assumed that redundant memory loads would detrimental to performance and tries to avoid them as much as possible. It's also clear that I should take advantage of masks much more! I'll thoroughly study your code to make sure I understand it as much as I can!

TL:DR: I made a version that builds a bitmap of X positions, of M positions, etc., then throws around whole rows of 140 bits in __m256i vectors to shift, AND, and popcount.  Pretty good with AVX2, excellent with AVX-512.

SIMD isn't trivial for this problem, but density of matches is high enough that brute force looks good, especially when cleverly applied to get the most data processing work done with each instruction (high information density in registers).  A good vectorization strategy depends on the ISA (e.g. AArch64 NEON/ASIMD vs. SVE, or x86-64 with AVX2 vs. AVX-512.  Or RISC-V extension V).  The strategy I came up with needs efficient vector to bitmask and vector popcount, which AVX-512 has.
(AArch64 has efficient vpopcount, but only SVE (not NEON) has efficient vector to bitmap, and only if you're storing it to memory.  We are, so SVE should work for this.  At least for a specific hardware width; making it scalable to hardware vectors other than 256-bit would be a challenge; could just query + dispatch to specialized versions.)
Using AVX2 on i7-6700k Skylake at 3.9 GHz, I can get about 7 GiB/s throughput (repeatedly processing the same 140x140 20k text file I loaded once, so I'm mostly getting L1d cache hits, and not paying the cost of mmaping a large file into memory.)
I didn't want to futz with tuning I/O and memory bottlenecks, or do the extra work of cache-blocking and/or multi-threading to try to overlap I/O with processing.  These processing speeds are so high that it could be significant, but low enough that HW prefetch into L2 should keep up if cache-blocking is done correctly.  This much took enough hours already. (Still untested for correctness, but written fairly carefully, and the asm doesn't look like anything optimized away that shouldn't).
Using AVX-512 with 256-bit vectors on 9600X Zen 5 at 5.45 GHz, I get an impressive 30 GiB/s.  (35.7 GiB/s using 512-bit vectors for building bitmaps and still 256-bit for finding XMAS in the bitboard maps).  Everything hits in its 48K L1d.  The system has over 56 GB/s single-thread mem B/W, so with HW prefetch and cache-blocking (for L2 size) for building bitmaps, it's plausible we could get somewhere in that ballpark of throughput.  36 GiB/s seems like a lot for how much work we're doing per byte, but L1d cache read bandwidth for a single core is about 640 GiB/s (2x 64-byte loads / clock.)
My AVX2 version on Zen 5 runs about 17 GiB/s, averaging 5 instructions per cycle vs. 2.89 on Skylake.  (Built with clang++ 18.1 -O3 -fno-plt -march=x86-64-v3 -mtune=znver4 -mbranches-within-32B-boundaries.  -march=skylake is ironically about 1% slower on SKL.  Clang 18 doesn't support -march/-mtune=znver5 yet, that's new in Clang 19.)
With a grid 256 characters wide, this same strategy would only need a bit more work building bitmaps, and no extra work checking them.  (Or 253 anyway).  This is all single-threaded; with mmap I/O it should scale until mem bandwidth limits.

The density of matches is high enough that SIMD brute-force looks very good here, if we can figure out how to AND together compare results for v0 == 'X', v1 == 'M', v2 == 'A', v3 == 'S', such that the right element for each lines up to check an up, down, left, right, or diagonal so we're checking 32 or 64 candidates at once.
Using SIMD to find a substring or a starting point for scalar checking could make sense in a less dense grid, like how libc memchr is implemented.  memmem or strstr can also use SIMD to some degree, but we need to check diagonals and verticals where characters aren't contiguous within the same vector so that part is a quite different problem.  And with high density, we'd only be scanning less than 1 vector before finding the next X, or like looping over the X positions in a bitmap of compare results (with std::countr_zero and map &= map-1 (BLSR).  So lots of data-dependent branches that wouldn't predict well.
Homer512's answer shows how to use SIMD in a simple brute-force way, loading from different offsets such that element i of each vector lines up with the same element in another vector, i.e. forms part of the same potential XMAS.  So vectors from the next 3 rows for vertical, overlapping vectors for horizontal (offset by 1 byte each), and both for diagonal.  4x vpcmpeqb to get 0/-1 elements, 3x vpand to get a -1 only where all 4 vectors had the byte we're looking for.  Summing those 0 / -1 counts by subtracting from an accumulator vector (and widening from 8 to 64-bit elements to avoid overflow) is a very similar problem to How to count character occurrences using SIMD.
Or actually, Homer512 used AVX-512, so compares produce an integer bitmask not a vector, thus he uses kmov reg, k0 / popcnt.  AVX-512 supports masking so you can get the AND for free with masked compare-into-mask.  Unaligned 512-bit loads aren't ideal; each is a cache-line split.  But Homer512's answer is great for simplicity, elegantly factored into a forwards-backwards check that takes a stride.
AArch64 SVE also has compare-into-mask and could I think be used the same way.
One downside is having to handle the ends of rows repeatedly.
Also, you're "only" looking at 32 or 64 elements at a time.  Every byte of the grid gets compared multiple times for being either an X, M, A, or S, and those results ANDed multiple times.
So what if you compare into bitmaps once, then use SIMD to AND 256-bit vectors of whole rows at a time?
This is like the bitboard idea from a chess engine: an X vector where each bit represents the position of an X in a row, an M vector, etc.  In a chess engine, you'd have a uint64_t where the set bits represent pawn positions, or positions those pawns can attack, or whatever.  The 8x8 = 64 square size of a chess board is perfect for modern computers, not wasting any bits.  But even a factor of just over 4 (8 * 140/256) is good despite the extra cost to shift it, leaving nearly half the bits in an __m256i unused for this inconvenient 140-wide grid if we just aim for one row per vector so they line up nicely.
Finding vertical up/down matches can then be done a whole row at a time, with just three vector AND operations between X, M, A, and S row bitmaps for subsequent rows.  Horizontal and diagonal need us to shift the vectors by 1, 2, or 3 bits, which isn't ideal but can still be done in 4 instructions (AVX2: vpermq + shift+shift + OR) or 2 (AVX-512VBMI2 vpermq + vpshldq), and we can reuse those shifted vectors as part of later diagonals and horizontals if we're clever about it.
ANDing four vectors together, we get a bitmap of matches for a starting row for one direction.  (140 useful bits out of the 256 we generate.)  Then we need to do counts += vector_popcount(down_left_matches); for example; AVX2 can split a vector into odd/even nibbles for vpshufb lookup-tables.  All but the earliest AVX512 CPUs have VPOPCNTQ which counts bits within each 64-bit element.  (We can horizontal sum at the end, outside the outer loop, of course.)
A 512-bit vector can hold three 140-bit rows and still have each one start at a 32-bit boundary for shuffling with valignd (so rounding up to 160 bits = 20 bytes per row bitmap).  I'm not sure how well that works for diagonals; I think unaligned loads would work, and the penalty for that would pay for itself in doing 3x the work per instruction, especially on Intel and Zen 5 where 512-bit instructions have nearly the same throughput as 256-bit.  Or we could give each row a 256-bit half of a 512-bit vector so every other is aligned.
(But reusing shift results is harder with 3 rows per vector: we want a shift computed for row+2 to be used at row+1 and row+0. Maybe just redo those shifts, or maybe we can use valignd to shift data between vectors. If we actually store/reload, we'd have store-forwarding stalls, and it doesn't work where the circular buffer wraps even if we did SoA instead AoS. X3 and S3 are maybe fine; row+3 is congruent mod 3 to row+0. So there's still a significant speedup to be had, but it's not a factor of 3 even if 512-bit instruction throughputs are pretty much the same as 256-bit (which is close to the case on Zen 5 I think.))

The other part of the trick here is to do as much as we can with a row of data while we have it in a register. And to avoid redoing the same 256-bit shift.  A small circular buffer of recent shifted-vector results generated while checking for diagonals can be reloaded when checking for horizontal.
With AVX-512 for 32 vector regs, clang 18 (unlike 19) will actually unroll by 4 and optimize away the array of structs of 6 __m256i, and avoid any instructions copying registers.  This also avoids the integer insns for address math for the recent array.
AVX2 has much worse register pressure since it "only" has 16, and it needs a couple vector constants for vector popcount.  Manually unrolling by 4 could still help, at least avoiding the integer address math (which would probably help on Skylake or Ice Lake, where the front-end is a bottleneck according to https://uica.uops.info/, at least for GCC's version.)
Enough talk, here's the code
It's not pretty, and still full of design-notes comments.  I haven't attempted to make full use of AVX-512 for count_XMAS(), although Clang 18.1 -march=znver4 unrolls the __m256i version by 4 and optimizes recent[] into registers.
main reads the file once, then alternates calls to build_maps and count_XMAS_AVX2.
Hmm, mask-building can be interleaved into the count loop, using a circular buffer of bitmaps. e.g. making a bitmap for row+7 or row+15 while we're processing row+0..3.  You want to be far enough ahead that you don't get store-forwarding stalls from 64-bit kmov stores being reloaded by 256-bit vector loads.  On Intel, having 512-bit uops in flight shuts down port 1's vector ALUs, so mixing 512 and 256 isn't ideal.  Not so on Zen 4 or even Zen 5; Zen 5 is a beast with 4/clock vpandq zmm, 2/clock ZMM shifts and shuffles including vpermq, and 2/clock 64-byte load.  (ZMM store is 2 uops, 2x 256-bit store buffer entries.)
Handling of the first 3 rows is bogus: vertical and diagonal matches will be ignored since I just zero-init recent[] instead of populating it with shifted vectors.  The last 3 rows aren't checked for horizontal matches, but are checked for vertical and diagonal.  So I've calculated throughput based on the 134 rows we fully process.
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static constexpr int gridsize = 140;
static constexpr int gridwidth = gridsize;   // ASSUMPTION: square grid.
using Grid = std::array< std::array<char, gridwidth+1>, gridsize >;    // with newlines at the end of each line
static const int VEC_WIDTH = 32;

struct Maps {
    static constexpr int row_chunks = ((gridwidth + 255) / 256);  // Number of 32B chunks of bitmap data
    // in the problem given, it's 1 chunk, so we're just going to use that without really looping
    // actually just barely wider than a 128-bit vector; if we didn't have cheap 32-byte vectors, we'd do one 16-byte + a 4-byte integer
    alignas(__m256i) uint32_t X[gridwidth][8 * row_chunks];   // zero-padded so we can load + AND full vectors without false-positives
    alignas(__m256i) uint32_t M[gridwidth][8 * row_chunks];
    alignas(__m256i) uint32_t A[gridwidth][8 * row_chunks];
    alignas(__m256i) uint32_t S[gridwidth][8 * row_chunks];
    // optionally add padding if it's useful to allow safely reading past the end of the last array
    static_assert( 32 /*bits in uint32_t*/ == VEC_WIDTH, "Maps element size should match vector width");
};

// something in this benefits from being inlined with clang18 -march=znver4
__attribute__((noinline))
void build_maps(Maps *result, const Grid &grid)
{
    __m256i Xs = _mm256_set1_epi8('X');
    __m256i Ms = _mm256_set1_epi8('M');
    __m256i As = _mm256_set1_epi8('A');
    __m256i Ss = _mm256_set1_epi8('S');
    for (int row=0 ; row<gridsize ; row++){
        int col = 0; // used after the loop for cleanup
        for ( ; col < gridwidth-(VEC_WIDTH-1) ; col += VEC_WIDTH){
            __m256i v = _mm256_loadu_si256( (const __m256i*) &(grid[row][col]) );
            // coding style: maybe loop an array of __m256i and an array of outputs bitmaps, to avoid manual "unroll" over XMAS
            // there's room to leave the *first* 32-bit elemnt 0 as well as the last few, allowing room to right shift if useful, but we don't do that.
            result->X[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm256_movemask_epi8( _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(v, Xs) );
            result->M[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm256_movemask_epi8( _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(v, Ms) );
            result->A[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm256_movemask_epi8( _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(v, As) );
            result->S[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm256_movemask_epi8( _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(v, Ss) );
        }
        if (col < gridwidth) {
            // HARDCODED ASSUMPTION: gridwidth >= 16, or at least that rows are padded.  Not worth doing just for building bitgrids.
            // HARDCODED ASSUMPTION: gridwidth % VECTOR_WIDTH <= 16.  Otherwise use a 32-byte vector
            __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*) &(grid[row][gridwidth-16]) );  // last 16 bytes of a row, avoids reading past end of last row.
            v = _mm_bsrli_si128(v, 4);  // 140 - 128 = 12 = 16-4
            // vpsrldq shifts in zeros at the top, giving us the 12 bytes we want plus high zeros which won't false-positive match anything
            result->X[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm256_castsi256_si128(Xs)) );
            result->M[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm256_castsi256_si128(Ms)) );
            result->A[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm256_castsi256_si128(As)) );
            result->S[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm256_castsi256_si128(Ss)) );
        }
    }
}

#ifdef __AVX512BW__
__attribute__((noinline))
void build_maps_AVX512(Maps *result, const Grid &grid)
{
    __m512i Xs = _mm512_set1_epi8('X');
    __m512i Ms = _mm512_set1_epi8('M');
    __m512i As = _mm512_set1_epi8('A');
    __m512i Ss = _mm512_set1_epi8('S');
    for (int row=0 ; row<gridsize ; row++){
        int col = 0; // used after the loop for cleanup
        // VEC_WIDTH = 32 wasn't a good design for source that can compile to AVX2 or AVX-512 since indexing the u32 elements depends on VEC_WIDTH
        for ( ; col < gridwidth-(VEC_WIDTH*2-1) ; col += VEC_WIDTH*2){
            __m512i v = _mm512_loadu_si512( &(grid[row][col]) );
            // TODO: verify _store_mask64 is supposed to be strict-aliasing safe, else use memcpy
            _store_mask64( (__mmask64*) &result->X[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0], _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(v, Xs) );
            _store_mask64( (__mmask64*) &result->M[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0], _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(v, Ms) );
            _store_mask64( (__mmask64*) &result->A[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0], _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(v, As) );
            _store_mask64( (__mmask64*) &result->S[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0], _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(v, Ss) );
        }
        if (col < gridwidth) {
            __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*) &(grid[row][gridwidth-16]) );  // last 16 bytes of a row, avoids reading past end of last row.
            v = _mm_bsrli_si128(v, 4);  // 140 - 128 = 12 = 16-4
            result->X[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm512_castsi512_si128(Xs)) );
            result->M[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm512_castsi512_si128(Ms)) );
            result->A[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm512_castsi512_si128(As)) );
            result->S[row][col/VEC_WIDTH + 0] = _mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v, _mm512_castsi512_si128(Ss)) );
        }
    }
}
#endif


// aligned load with a short name to wrap the noisy casting
// AVX-512 loads take void* but AVX and earlier don't.
static inline __m256i load256(const void *p) {
    return _mm256_load_si256( (const __m256i*)p );
}

#ifdef __AVX512VPOPCNTDQ__
inline __m256i vpopcount(__m256i vec){
    return _mm256_popcnt_epi64(vec);
}
#define add_counts  _mm256_add_epi64
inline __m256i widen_count8(__m256i v){ return v; }  // counts are actually already 64-bit

#else  // without AVX-512 vpopcntq
// for adding vpopcount results within the inner loop, before hsumming within u64 elements
// could just always use vpaddq since it's not slower on any AVX2 CPUs, and we need to avoid carry-out from the top of an element regardless
#define add_counts  _mm256_add_epi8
inline __m256i  widen_count8(__m256i count8){
    return _mm256_sad_epu8(count8, _mm256_setzero_si256());
}
inline __m256i vpopcount(__m256i vec){
//  return _mm256_popcnt_epi8(vec);  // __AVX512BITALG__ CPUs also have VPOPCNTQ, avoiding the need for PSADBW
    // https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount
    const __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8(
        /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
        /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
        /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
        /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4,

        /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
        /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
        /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
        /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4
        );
    const __m256i low_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0f);

    const __m256i lo  = _mm256_and_si256(vec, low_mask);  // odd-even split.
    const __m256i hi  = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(vec, 4), low_mask);
    // If we could preprocess the bitmap to 7 or fewer bits per byte (high bit always clear for pshufb), that would avoid the ANDs
    // But then shifts would be much harder.
    const __m256i popcnt1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, lo);
    const __m256i popcnt2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, hi);
    return _mm256_add_epi8(popcnt1, popcnt2);
}
#endif  // helper functions without AVX512VPOPCNT

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108658/fastest-method-to-calculate-sum-of-all-packed-32-bit-integers-using-avx512-or-av
static inline uint64_t hsum128_epi64(__m128i v) {
    __m128i hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(v,v);
    v = _mm_add_epi64(v, hi);
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si64(v);
}
static inline uint64_t hsum256_epi64(__m256i v){
    __m128i sum128 = _mm_add_epi64( _mm256_castsi256_si128(v),
                    _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 1));
    return hsum128_epi64(sum128);
}

template<unsigned count>
static inline
__m256i shl256(__m256i v)
{
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367822/how-to-implement-lane-crossing-logical-bit-wise-shift-rotate-left-and-right-in for runtime-variable shifts allowing a count higher than 64.
    static_assert(count < 64, "we only handle small shift counts where bits come from the adjacent element.  Use if(count)");

    __m256i carry =  _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,0,3));  // vpermq rotate by qwords.
#if defined(__AVX512VBMI2__) && defined(__AVX512VL__)
    return _mm256_shldi_epi64(v, carry, count);   // vpshldq
#else
    carry = _mm256_srli_epi64(carry, 64-count);
    v = _mm256_slli_epi64(v, count);
    v = _mm256_or_si256(v, carry);  // OR in the n bits from the element below this.
                                    // Or zeros from the top into the bottom: gridsize+3 <= 256.  This avoids an AND to clear any bits
    return v;
#endif
    // 4 instructions, but remember we're dealing with a whole row of 140 elements (bits) at a time.
}

// Will use some AVX-512 if available via helper functions, and compiler optimization to vpternlogq, so actually YMM not necessarily AVX2
__attribute__((noinline))
uint64_t count_XMAS_AVX2(const Maps &maps)
{
    // buffer on the stack to store shifted vectors, since it costs multiple instructions.  Reloads can be cheap, folded into memory source operands.
    struct RecentRows {
        __m256i X3;     // Only X<<0 and X<<3 ever needed
        __m256i M1, M2;  // only <<1 and <<2 ever needed
        __m256i A1, A2;  // only <<1 and <<2 ever needed
        __m256i S3;
        // Maybe some other order for efficiency of contiguous stores (e.g. Ice Lake)?
        // maybe pad to make its size a power of 2 for more efficient indexing?
    } recent[4] = {};         // circular buffer, index with  row & 3.  Or does row & 7 save any insns if unrolling?
    // FIXME: init recent rows for loop entry.  Or pad grid with 3 rows of zeros if we just care about large-case performance.
    // for now, I'm just reporting throughput for 137 rows, since that's all we fully check for horizontal.  Actually 134 since we don't do the vector-shifting work for the first 2 rows, and only part of it for the 3rd row.
    // The question was focused on throughput for large-scale inputs...

    // up/down: pure vertical bitwise AND: X[r] & M[r+1] ... and the reverse order, r+3 .. r+0  (always starting from [r] as the earliest row)
    // horizontal: left-to-right: shift the X to the same pos as the ending S, etc:  X[r]<<3 & M[r]<<2 & A[r]<<1 & S[r]<<0
                // right-to-left: X[r] & M[r]<<1 ...
    // always shift left so we can reuse shifted copies
    __m256i counts = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    for (int row = 0 ; row < gridsize - (4-1) ; row+=1){
        // HARDCODED ASSUMPTION: one __m256i holds all the bits from a whole row, ending with at least 3 zeros to avoid false positives when we shift them into the bottom
        // grid width <= 253.   (Shifting bits out the top is fine, those are where the XMAS would have to extend outside the grid)
        __m256i Xr0 = load256( &maps.X[row] );
        __m256i Sr0 = load256( &maps.S[row] );
        // Horizontal, using shifted vectors already generated for diagonals when this was row+3 (X,S) or row+2 (M,A)
        __m256i right_matches = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[row & 3].X3, recent[row & 3].M2),
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[row & 3].A1, Sr0) );
        __m256i left_matches = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(Xr0, recent[row & 3].M2),
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[row & 3].A1, recent[row&3].S3) );

        // For now, just accumulate 8-bit counts within the inner loop, widen at the end
        __m256i count8 = vpopcount(right_matches) + vpopcount(left_matches);  // _mm256_add_epi8, or let GNU extensions use vpaddq
        // Alternative: Harley-Seal instead of popcounting each result on the spot, but that would use up even more vector regs.

        __m256i Mr1 = load256( &maps.M[row+1] );
        __m256i Mr2 = load256( &maps.M[row+2] );
        __m256i Ar1 = load256( &maps.A[row+1] );
        __m256i Ar2 = load256( &maps.A[row+2] );
        __m256i Xr3 = load256( &maps.X[row+3] );
        __m256i Sr3 = load256( &maps.S[row+3] );
        // vertical matches: no shifting needed
        __m256i down_matches = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(Xr0, Mr1),
            _mm256_and_si256(Ar2, Sr3)  );
        __m256i up_matches = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(Xr3, Mr2),
            _mm256_and_si256(Ar1, Sr0)  );

        count8 += vpopcount(down_matches);
        count8 += vpopcount(up_matches);

    // diagonal: down-right: X[r]<<3   & M[r+1]<<2 & A[r+2]<<1 & S[r+3]
    //           down-left:  X[r]      & M[r+1]<<1 & A[r+2]<<2 & S[r+3]<<3
    //       up-left:    X[r+3]    & M[r+2]<<1 & A[r+1]<<2 & S[r+0]<<3
    //           up-right:   X[r+3]<<3 & M[r+2]<<2 & A[r+1]<<1 & S[r+0]
        // should only need the same subset of row masks as verticals, but now need to shift them.
        recent[(row+2)&3].M1 = shl256<1>(Mr2);
        recent[(row+2)&3].M2 = shl256<2>(Mr2);
        recent[(row+2)&3].A1 = shl256<1>(Ar2);
        recent[(row+2)&3].A2 = shl256<2>(Ar2);
        //row+1 Mr1 and Ar1 shifts already done last iteration when it was row+2
        //row+0 X and S shifts done earlier, too
        recent[(row+3)&3].S3 = shl256<3>(Sr3);
        recent[(row+3)&3].X3 = shl256<3>(Xr3);
        __m256i down_right = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[row&3].X3,     recent[(row+1)&3].M2),
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[(row+2)&3].A1, Sr3) );
        __m256i down_left = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(Xr0,                  recent[(row+1)&3].M1),
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[(row+2)&3].A2, recent[(row+3)&3].S3) );

        count8 += vpopcount(down_right);
        count8 += vpopcount(down_left);
        __m256i up_left = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(Xr3,                  recent[(row+2)&3].M1),
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[(row+1)&3].A2, recent[(row+0)&3].S3) );
        __m256i up_right = _mm256_and_si256(
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[(row+3)&3].X3, recent[(row+2)&3].M2),
            _mm256_and_si256(recent[(row+1)&3].A1, Sr0) );
        count8 += vpopcount(up_left);
        count8 += vpopcount(up_right);

        // Do some more iterations, row+1 to row+4, then row+2 to row+5, row+3 to row+6 trying to reuse things already in registers?
        // row += 4;
        // Clang 18 already unrolls that way with -march=znver4, keeping recent[] in registers.

        // we can add up to 15x vpopcount8 results without risk of overflow of any element.  (16 * 26 = 256)
        // For this use-case, at least twice as many because XMAS forward can't also be XMAS backward
        counts = _mm256_add_epi64(counts, widen_count8(count8));
        // AVX512 with vpopcntq: widen is a no-op.  To save regs, could drop count8, only add into counts
    }
    return hsum256_epi64(counts);
}

    // AVX-512
    // two rows at a time in the 256-bit halves of an __m512i.  Or even 3 rows per __m512i?  3*140 is 420 bits, plenty to spare.
    // rounding up length to 160 bits so each row starts at a u32 boundary, 3*160 = 480 bits.

    // twice as many registers makes it practical to reuse load and shift results without store/reload, if unrolling enough
    // vpternlogd for 3-input booleans: compiler will optimize and_si256 into ternlog instructions
    // AVX-512VBMI2: unaligned load or VPALIGND to feed VPSHLD to shift bits from one reg into another
    // AVX-512VPOPCNT:  vpopcntq is obviously great.  vpternlogd for harley-seal maybe not worth it, but useful with just AVX512F
    //   no real CPUs with VPOPCNT but not VBMI/VBMI2 except Knight's Mill, and only Skylake/Cascade/Cooper Lake / Knight's Landing had AVX512 without VPOPCNT.


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1){
        std::cerr << "usage: wordsearch  input.txt\n";
        return 1;
    }

    //static char grid[gridsize][gridwidth + 1];  // with newlines at the end of each line
    static Grid grid;
    static Maps maps = {};
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int readsize = fread(&grid, gridsize+1, gridsize, fp);  // TODO: look up the C++ way to do this
    if (readsize != 140){
        std::cerr << "wrong input size: " << readsize << " records of " << gridsize+1 << " bytes, expected " << gridsize << "\n";
        return 2;
    }

    uint64_t count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<1000000 ; i++) {
        asm("" :: "r"(&maps), "r"(&grid) : "memory");  // DoNotOptimize
        #ifdef __AVX512BW__
        build_maps_AVX512(&maps, grid);
        #else
        build_maps(&maps, grid);
        #endif
        asm("" :: "r"(&maps) : "memory");  // pretend the map was modified
        count += count_XMAS_AVX2(maps);
    }

    std::cout << "count = " << count << "\n";
}

(Godbolt : only room for a short link due to the 30k character limit on SO posts.)
The asm statements prevent the compiler from hoisting work out of the loop.  The optimizer thinks a black-box function got pointers to maps and grid, and the "memory" clobber makes it assume that the function modified any/every byte it could reach from those and globals.
I even made the functions __attribute__((noinline)) so they have to redo setting up their constants and allocating stack space.
# x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux, GCC 14.2.1

$ g++ -O3 -fno-plt -mtune=skylake -march=native -Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries -Wall -Wno-parentheses -g ~/src/SO/advent2024-4-SIMD-wordsearch.cpp -o wsearch.gcc.skylake

$ perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,idq.mite_uops,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread ./wsearch.gcc.skylake grid.txt
count = 2306000000

 Performance counter stats for './wsearch.gcc.skylake grid.txt':

   2,663.59 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
          0      context-switches              #    0.000 /sec                      
          0      cpu-migrations                #    0.000 /sec                      
        135      page-faults                   #   50.683 /sec                      
10,367,381,278      cycles                     #    3.892 GHz                       
31,601,580,612      instructions               #    3.05  insn per cycle            
   159,195,653      idq.mite_uops              #   59.767 M/sec                     
33,038,360,975      uops_issued.any            #   12.404 G/sec                     
35,388,753,648      uops_executed.thread       #   13.286 G/sec                     

  2.664128036 seconds time elapsed

  2.662215000 seconds user
  0.000000000 seconds sys

(energy_performance_preference = balance_performance, so my mobo chooses to only go to 3.9GHz, not 4.2 GHz turbo.)
Clang does somewhat better, 2528 msec, 9.85 Gcycles, 28.6 G instructions (2.90  insn per cycle)
Omitting one or the other from the repeat loop, Skylake takes 1.15s for just build_map, 1.56s for just count_XMAS

Thank you very much for this incredible answer! I do appreciate the comments as your implementation is more complicated than Homer512's. I'm grateful though as I get to study both a "naive" use of AVX for brute forcing the problem and a more in depth implementation. I'll study both answers thoroughly so I can improve from them. It'll also be interesting to see the throughput I can get from them as I have a Zen 4 7900
