# Emulating shifts on 64 bytes with AVX-512

Tags: simd, avx512

My question is an extension of a previous question: [Emulating shifts on 32 bytes with AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248766/emulating-shifts-on-32-bytes-with-avx/25264853#25264853).

How do I implement similar shifts on 64 bytes with AVX-512? Specifically, how should I implement:

- `__m512i _mm512_slli_si512(__m512i a, int imm8)`
- `__m512i _mm512_srli_si512(__m512i a, int imm8)`

Corrosponding to the SSE2 methods [`_mm_slli_si128`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_slli_si128&expand=5236,4941,4950,4941,4950,636,1882,5149,5191,5521,636,1874,5321,5321&techs=SSE2) and [`_mm_srli_si128`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_srli_si128&expand=5236,4941,4950,4941,4950,636,1882,5149,5191,5521,636,1874,5321,5321,5533&techs=SSE2).

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to store and reload the data (if necessary, using `_mm512_maskz_loadu_epi8`).

Comment: For the case where `imm8` is a constexpr and multiple of 8, you can use AVX512F [`valignd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/valignd:valignq) for a dword-granularity shift of the whole vector.  Otherwise maybe use that as a building block along with `_mm512_shrdi_epi16` 2-register shift (AVX512_VBMI2 so IceLake and newer...)  Which AVX512 extensions can you use, or which CPUs do you care about?

Comment: @PeterCordes `valignd` should actually work for multiples of 4 (i.e., 32 bits), shouldn't it? (which kind of leaves the question what the point of `valignq` is ...)

Comment: @chtz Any chance you could add your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @PeterCordes Skylake ideally

Comment: @chtz: yes, I meant to write multiple of 32 bits but somehow forgot to actually edit that sentence after remembering valignd != vpalignr.  Anyway, the point of `valignq` is to apply a mask bitmap to qword elements.   (Same reason we have `vpxord` and `vpxorq` instead of just extending AVX2 `vpxor`)

Comment: @Daniel: The following would work, if it wasn't for strict-aliasing rules in C/C++: https://godbolt.org/z/OKao8F. But even if it did, you should provide the temporary array (filled with zeros at the end) only once outside any critical loop -- and make sure not to access it from multiple threads. Or, instead of filling the temporary with zeros, use a masked load. And whether that is optimal or some shifting tricks really depends on the context or the amount you need to shift (e.g., if you want to shift by a multiply of 32bit,  `valignd` is most likely better).

Comment: My previous attempt did not work, because I messed up the size of AVX512 registers ... I just posted a working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution using a temporary array:

```
__m512i _mm512_slri_si512(__m512i a, size_t imm8)
{
    // set up temporary array and set upper half to zero 
    // (this needs to happen outside any critical loop)
    alignas(64) char temp[128];
    _mm512_store_si512(temp+64, _mm512_setzero_si512());

    // store input into lower half
    _mm512_store_si512(temp, a);

    // load shifted register
    return _mm512_loadu_si512(temp+imm8);
}

__m512i _mm512_slli_si512(__m512i a, size_t imm8)
{
    // set up temporary array and set lower half to zero 
    // (this needs to happen outside any critical loop)
    alignas(64) char temp[128];
    _mm512_store_si512(temp, _mm512_setzero_si512());

    // store input into upper half
    _mm512_store_si512(temp+64, a);

    // load shifted register
    return _mm512_loadu_si512(temp+(64-imm8));
}
```

This should also work if `imm8` was not known at compile time, but it does not do any out-of-bounds checks.
You could actually use a `3*64` temporary and share it between the left and right shift methods (and both would work for negative inputs as well).

Of course, if you share a temporary outside the function body, you must make sure that it is not accessed by multiple threads at once.

Godbolt-Link with usage demonstration: https://godbolt.org/z/LSgeWZ

---

As Peter noted, **this store-load trick will cause a store-forwarding stall on all CPUs with AVX512**.  The most-efficient forwarding case (~6 cycle latency) only works when all the load bytes come from one store.  If the load goes outside the most recent store that overlaps it at all, it has extra latency (like ~16 cycles) to scan the store buffer and if needed merge in bytes from L1d cache.  See [Can modern x86 implementations store-forward from more than one prior store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135766/can-modern-x86-implementations-store-forward-from-more-than-one-prior-store) and [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/)for more details. This extra-scanning process can probably be happening for multiple loads in parallel, and at least doesn't stall other things (like normal store-forwarding or the rest of the pipeline), so it may not be a throughput problem.

If you want many shift offsets of the same data, one store and multiple reloads at different alignments should be good.

But if latency is your primary issue you should try a solution based on `valignd` (also, if you want to shift by a multiple of 4 bytes that is obviously an easier solution).  Or for constant shift-counts, a vector control for `vpermw` could work.

---

For completeness, here is a version based on `valignd` and `valignr` working for shifts from 0 to 64, known at compile-time (using C++17 -- but you can easily avoid the `if constexpr` this is only here because of the `static_assert`). Instead of shifting in zeros you can pass a second register (i.e., it behaves like `valignr` would behave if it would align across lanes).

```
template<int N>
__m512i shift_right(__m512i a, __m512i carry = _mm512_setzero_si512())
{
  static_assert(0 <= N && N <= 64);
  if constexpr(N   == 0) return a;
  if constexpr(N   ==64) return carry;
  if constexpr(N%4 == 0) return _mm512_alignr_epi32(carry, a, N / 4);
  else
  {
    __m512i a0 = shift_right< (N/16 + 1)*16>(a, carry);  // 16, 32, 48, 64
    __m512i a1 = shift_right< (N/16    )*16>(a, carry);  //  0, 16, 32, 48
    return _mm512_alignr_epi8(a0, a1, N % 16);
  }
}

template<int N>
__m512i shift_left(__m512i a, __m512i carry = _mm512_setzero_si512())
{
  return shift_right<64-N>(carry, a);
}
```

Here is a godbolt-link with some example assembly as well as output for every possible `shift_right` operation: https://godbolt.org/z/xmKJvA

GCC faithfully translates this into `valignd` and `valignr` instructions -- but may do an unnecessary `vpxor` instruction (e.g. in the `shiftleft_49` example), Clang does some crazy substitutions (not sure if they actually make a difference, though).

The code could be extended to shift an arbitrary sequence of registers (always carrying bytes from the previous register).

Comment: You should point out that this guarantees a store-forwarding stall; ~16 cycle latency instead of ~6.  It's not generally a throughput problem, though, so this might be good for some use-cases.  (it's not a "stall" as in stalling the whole pipeline.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the hint (I had to read up on that first). I guess a masked load (or store) won't help much either here?

Comment: Good question; it's plausible that a load which doesn't *actually* take any data from outside the store could avoid a stall.  But probably unlikely; the HW would have to bitscan the mask for the lowest and highest set bits to support that in the overlap check.  I assume that in practice the cache + store-buffer provide the full 64 bytes of data to the load port, and it's discarded there.  For the same reason, cache-line split penalties are (I think) based on the full width of a load before considering the mask.

Comment: But note that stores don't have to make it to L1d; a store-forwarding "stall" doesn't mean complete failure, it just means taking the slow case of presumably scanning the whole store buffer plus L1d to combine bytes instead of just finding the first match.  If it had to commit to L1d, cache-miss stores between the store and reload could create very large delays, but AFAIK that's not the case.  See [Can modern x86 implementations store-forward from more than one prior store?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46145326) for my understanding of this process.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm way out of my comfort zone regarding store-forwarding. Feel free to add a link or note which better explains that issue.

Comment: Note that this fails on GCC unfortunately: `error: '_mm512_loadu_epi32' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_mm512_load_epi32'`

Comment: @Daniel `_mm512_loadu_si512` appears to work with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/LSgeWZ (edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

For those who need to shift by exactly 64 bits, you can use the permute instruction which is directly going to work in registers. For a shift by a multiple of 8 bits, you could use the byte shuffle (see `VPSHUFB` and look at the cast functions if you are dealing with floats as the shuffles uses integers).

Here is an example to shift by 64 bits (*"SHR zmm1, 64"*). The mask is used to clear the top 64 bits. If you want to `ROR` like functionality, you can use the version without the mask. Note that it's possible to do a shift to the left as well. Just change the indexes as required.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

void show(char const * msg, double *v)
{
    std::cout
            << msg
            << ": "
            << v[0]
            << " "
            << v[1]
            << " "
            << v[2]
            << " "
            << v[3]
            << " "
            << v[4]
            << " "
            << v[5]
            << " "
            << v[6]
            << " "
            << v[7]
            << "\n";
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double v[8] = { 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8. };
    double q[8] = {};
    alignas(64) std::uint64_t indexes[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0 };

    show("init", v);
    show("q", q);

    // load
    __m512d a(_mm512_loadu_pd(v));
    __m512i i(_mm512_load_epi64(indexes));

    // shift
    //__m512d b(_mm512_permutex_pd(a, 0x39));   // can't cross between 4 low and 4 high with immediate
    //__m512d b(_mm512_permutexvar_pd(i, a));   // ROR
    __m512d b(_mm512_maskz_permutexvar_pd(0x7F, i, a));   // LSR on a double basis

    // store
    _mm512_storeu_pd(q, b);

    show("shifted", q);
    show("original", v);
}
```

Fully optimized output (-O3) reduces the whole shift to 3 instructions (which are intermingled with others in the output):

```
 96a:   62 f1 fd 48 6f 85 10    vmovdqa64 -0xf0(%rbp),%zmm0
 971:   ff ff ff 
 974:   b8 7f 00 00 00          mov    $0x7f,%eax              # mask
 979:   48 8d 3d 10 04 00 00    lea    0x410(%rip),%rdi        # d90 <_IO_stdin_used+0x10>
 980:   c5 f9 92 c8             kmovb  %eax,%k1                # special k1 register
 984:   4c 89 e6                mov    %r12,%rsi
 987:   62 f2 fd c9 16 85 d0    vpermpd -0x130(%rbp),%zmm0,%zmm0{%k1}{z}   # "shift"
 98e:   fe ff ff 
 991:   62 f1 fd 48 11 45 fe    vmovupd %zmm0,-0x80(%rbp)
```

In my case, I want to use that in a loop and the load (`vmovdqa64`) and store (`vmovupd`) are going to be before and after the loop, inside the loop, it will be really fast. (It needs to rotate that way 4,400 times before I need to save the result).

As pointed out by Peter, we can also use the `valignq` instruction:

```
// this is in place of the permute, without the need for the indexes
__m512i b(_mm512_maskz_alignr_epi64(0xFF, _mm512_castpd_si512(a), _mm512_castpd_si512(a), 1));
```

and the result is one instruction like so:

```
 979:   62 f1 fd 48 6f 85 d0    vmovdqa64 -0x130(%rbp),%zmm0
 980:   fe ff ff 
 983:   48 8d 75 80             lea    -0x80(%rbp),%rsi
 987:   48 8d 3d 02 04 00 00    lea    0x402(%rip),%rdi        # d90 <_IO_stdin_used+0x10>
 98e:   62 f3 fd 48 03 c0 01    valignq $0x1,%zmm0,%zmm0,%zmm0
 995:   62 f1 fd 48 11 45 fd    vmovupd %zmm0,-0xc0(%rbp)
```

An important point, using less registers is also much better since it increase our chances to get full optimizations 100% in registers instead of having to use memory (512 bits is a lot to transfer to and from memory).

Comment: You can use [`valignd` or q](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/valignd:valignq) to rotate a vector in 4 or 8-byte chunks, using an immediate count (no vector shuffle-control needed).  Unlike the terrible AVX2 version, it's fully lane-crossing.  You can shift in a zero from a zeroed vector (cheaper to set up), or use zero-masking like you're doing.  Also, if you *do* need a vector constant like `indexes`, it's usually best to use `_mm512_set_epi64`, definitely not a non-const non-static local array with alignas.