# implement _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps using AVX instructions

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx

The AVX2 intrinsic `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` can perform shuffling across the lanes, which is quite useful for sorting array of length 8.

Now I only have AVX (Ivy Bridge) and want to do the same thing in minimal cycles. Note that both data and index are input and unknown at compile-time.

For example, the array is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and indices are `[3,0,1,7,6,5,2,4]`, output should be `[4,1,2,8,7,6,3,5]`.

The control masks of most handy intrinsics must be constants (without the "var" suffix), thus not suitable in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer you question if you gave a specific example of what you want to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516585/shifting-sse-avx-registers-32-bits-left-and-right-while-shifting-in-zeros

Comment: ahh...I understand what you mean with not being constant.  Let me think about it and see if I come up with something.

Comment: I added code to do _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps in AVX to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To permute across lanes in AVX you can permute within lanes, then use `_mm256_permute2f128_ps` to swap lanes, and then blend.  For example.  Let's assume you want to change the array {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} to {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.  You can do that like this

```
__m256 t0 = _mm256_permute_ps(x, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 3, 2));
__m256 t1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(t0, t0, 41);
__m256 y = _mm256_blend_ps(t0, t1, 0x33);
```

`_mm256_permute2f128_ps` also [has a zeroing feature](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_permute2f128_ps.htm) which can be quite useful (see also the [Intel Intrinsics Guide Online](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)).  I used it in the code above to swap the first lane to the second lane and then zero the first lane.  See
[shifting-sse-avx-registers-32-bits-left-and-right-while-shifting-in-zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516585/shifting-sse-avx-registers-32-bits-left-and-right-while-shifting-in-zeros) for more details.

Edit: the permutevar intrinsics allow runtime permutes and are therefore not limited to compile time constants.  The code below is the `lookup8` function from [Agner Fog's Vector Class Library](http://agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass).

```
static inline Vec8f lookup8(Vec8i const & index, Vec8f const & table) {
#if INSTRSET >= 8 && VECTORI256_H > 1 // AVX2
#if defined (_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1700 && ! defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)        
    // bug in MS VS 11 beta: operands in wrong order. fixed in 11.0
    return _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(index), _mm256_castps_si256(table)); 
#elif defined (GCC_VERSION) && GCC_VERSION <= 40700 && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER) && !defined(__clang__)
        // Gcc 4.7.0 has wrong parameter type and operands in wrong order. fixed in version 4.7.1
    return _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(index), table);
#else
    // no bug version
    return _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(table, index);
#endif

#else // AVX
    // swap low and high part of table
    __m256  t1 = _mm256_castps128_ps256(_mm256_extractf128_ps(table, 1));
    __m256  t2 = _mm256_insertf128_ps(t1, _mm256_castps256_ps128(table), 1);
    // join index parts
    __m256i index2 = _mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(index.get_low()), index.get_high(), 1);
    // permute within each 128-bit part
    __m256  r0 = _mm256_permutevar_ps(table, index2);
    __m256  r1 = _mm256_permutevar_ps(t2,    index2);
    // high index bit for blend
    __m128i k1 = _mm_slli_epi32(index.get_high() ^ 4, 29);
    __m128i k0 = _mm_slli_epi32(index.get_low(),      29);
    __m256  kk = _mm256_insertf128_ps(_mm256_castps128_ps256(_mm_castsi128_ps(k0)), _mm_castsi128_ps(k1), 1);
    // blend the two permutes
    return _mm256_blendv_ps(r0, r1, kk);
#endif
}
```

Here are the `get_low` and `get_high` functions:

```
Vec2db get_low() const {
    return _mm256_castpd256_pd128(ymm);
}
Vec2db get_high() const {
    return _mm256_extractf128_pd(ymm,1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have added some detail. Any ideas?